# Preventing a TeamCity build triggering when a specific user commits a specific file that normally triggers a build

Tags: svn, build, triggers, teamcity

I have a file in the Repo root, which when committed by any user triggers a TC build. (Commits of any other file do not trigger builds).

When the build is trigged, part of the build process for the build agent (we only have 1), is to edit this file and commits it.  I dont not want this commit to trigger another build, or else I end up in an infinite build loop. (Actually a secondary custom rule further down the build rules prevents this loop, but still I don't want the build triggered at all.)

I'm a have tried just about every combination I can think of to enable this pair of rules to co-exist but the build is always triggered when the build agent commits.

So the goal is for commits to "BuildTrigger.txt" (by anyone expect SVN User "agent") to trigger a build...

The last attempt I tried was just to ignore commits to any file by the agent:-

---

**+:BuildTrigger.txt**

**-:user=AGENT;root=SVNROOT:****

---

Although i have also tried:-

---

**+:BuildTrigger.txt**

**-:user=AGENT;root=SVNROOT:/BuildTrigger.txt**

---

**+:BuildTrigger.txt**

**-:user=AGENT;root=SVNROOT:BuildTrigger.txt**

---

**+:BuildTrigger.txt**

**-:user=AGENT**

---

But whenever AGENT commits BuildTrigger.txt a build goes to the queue.

Any helps greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, is a build definitely being triggered when the agent commits or does it just show as a pending change. Because even when the rule is working it will still show as a pending change.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd build is queued as a result of the agent commiting the BuilgTrigger.txt file, and then a 2nd build starts once the original is complete. 

I did find this post on the TC forums http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5215658#5215658 which took me to http://http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-3363 where it suggests using the Trigger rule :- 

-:**
+:actionFile.txt
-:user=teamcity:actionFile.txt

Same problem, 2 Builds.

To "fix" it, I have had to add specific include rule for each user that should trigger a build. Ie.

+:user=user1:BuildTrigger.txt
+:user=user2:BuildTrigger.txt

Comment: typo in 2nd url , should be http://jetbrains.net/tracker/issue/TW-3363

Answer (score 1):

I was stuggling with this problem myself. My solution was to take your last attempt:

+:BuildTrigger.txt

-:user=AGENT

and change it to

+:BuildTrigger.txt

-:user=AGENT:**/*